# weird errors - C# application

Tags: c#, syntax-error

```
... other LOCs
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Chat
{
    class MyServer
    {
        try
        {
            IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("localhost");
            TcpListener myListener = new TcpListener(ip, 8000);

            myListener.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Local end point: " + myListener.LocalEndpoint);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error... " + e.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

Okay, I got really irritated - I get errors on:
- try -> "Invalid token 'try' in class, struct or interface member declaration
- `new TcpListener(ip, 8000);` -> for the `ip` argument: "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field 'ip'". I can declare it as static, but what is the point ?
- `myListener.Start();` -> 'myListener' is a field but used as a type
- `Console.WriteLine(...` -> is a method but used as a type.

Seriously, I never got such strange errors.
Is it because I opened the entire class in some wrong way or something ? I have another class which contains the `Main()` method, but that shouldn't be the problem... 
This is really annoying, any suggestions ?

Comment: Code cannot be at class level. You need a method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the try block in a method and not inside a class.

```
class A
{
    void func1()
    {
      try{

       }
      catch(Exception e)
      {

      }

    }

}
```

Comment: you may even put it in the constructor, if that is what you meant to do.

Comment: Yeah, ok... I just wanted for the code to execute directly by calling this class, but didn't really think that it should be in a method (or in my case - in the constructor directly).
I knew that there is 1 single thing that causes all the problems! :D